# combining off page navigation slide and parallax scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm relatively new to coding and have been working on a project. At its current state I'm finding difficulty combining off-screen navigation with parallax scrolling. I have tried making a div inside the wrapper (ineffective), changing the location of where the parallax scrolling is in the HTML (makes one feature work, or the other), and changing the css positioning (generally just makes the page melt, with a few outliers)

The goal, ultimately, is to have the parallax scrolling run underneath the navigation square and the side menu move the background as well.

The code is below, with placeholder pictures and info some dashed out modifications of things I've tried and failed. Like I said, I'm quite new so if there is anything amiss I would deeply appreciate the help.

I'm guessing I'm overlooking something moronic, or am trying the wrong combination of solutions.

Thank you for any assistance.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>What is Reality?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="websitebasefinal.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tennants.css"/>
    <script language="javascript" src="websitefinal.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


        <div id="side-menu" class="side-menu">          


        <a href="websitebasefinal.html">Home</a>
        <a href="">hai</a>
        <a href="">mark</a>
        <a href="">!</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="" id="second-links">Contact Us</a>
        </div>

        <div id="search-menu" class="search-menu">

         <p>What are you <br>looking for?<br>
         <input type="text" placeholder="...?">
        </div>


    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="insidewrapper">

            <div id="container-one">

                <div id="container-menu" onclick="openmenuside()">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left fa-lg" id="menubutton" style="color:#f1f1f1"></i>

                    <script>
                    $('#container-menu').click(function(){
                    $('#menubutton').toggleClass('fas fa-align-left fa-lg fas fa-times fa-lg')
                    });
                    </script>
                </div>

                <div id="container-search" onclick="opensearchside()">
                    <i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" id="searchbutton" style="color:#f1f1f1"></i>

                    <script>
                    $('#container-search').click(function(){
                    $('#searchbutton').toggleClass('fas fa-search fa-lg fas fa-times fa-lg')
                    });
                    </script>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tenantcontainer">
                <div class="bgimage1">
                    <div class="caption">
                    <span class="border">Scroll down</span>
                    <div class="content"><p>Here's where we talk about what's what daddy-o</div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="bgimage2">
                    <div class="caption">
                    <span class="border">Scroll down</span>
                    <div class="content"><p>Here's where we talk about what's what daddy-o</div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.bgimage1, .bgimage2, .bgimage3{
    position:relative;
    /*background-attachment:fixed;*/
    background-position:center;
    /*background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
    background-size:cover;
    z-index:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;

}

.bgimage1{
    background-image:url("evelynnteaser-1920X1080.jpg");
    height:100%;
}

.bgimage2{
    background-image:url("2017-eclipse-photos-01.jpg");
    height:100%;
}

.bgimage3{
    background-image:url("evelynnteaser-1920X1080.jpg");
    height:100%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.caption span.border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.content, .content p{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:70px;
    color:white;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color:#f1f1f1;
}
```

JS:

```
function openmenuside(){
    var side=document.getElementById("side-menu");
    var container=document.getElementById("wrapper");
    if (side.style.width=='320px'){
        side.style.width="0px";
        container.style.marginLeft="-620px";    
    }else{
        side.style.width="320px";
        container.style.marginLeft="-340px";
    }

}

function opensearchside(){
    var side=document.getElementById("search-menu");
    var container=document.getElementById("wrapper");
    if (side.style.width=='320px'){
        side.style.width="0px";
        container.style.marginLeft="-620px";    
    }else{
        side.style.width="320px";
        container.style.marginLeft="-900px";
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a working snippet of your code?

Comment: I would love to but am unsure how to go about doing so. What would you recommend, if possible?